# How do I verify my solution is correct for a circuit diagram?

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra, truth-table

The original problem:

[image: This is the original problem.]

The trouble I'm having is that I'm not sure at all if my boolean expressions from the circuit diagram for `(1)` are correct; I also know that I definitely did `(4)` wrong since I didn't end up having to use a NAND gate. Moreover, I don't know where I went wrong.

[image]

Comment: Well, clearly G4=0 is wrong. Try making a truth table like your (2) but use the schematic only, don't try to use your Boolean equation. You find your mistakes the same way we all do, by trying a different approach and comparing results.

Comment: ah i see, thank u